# Як потрібно відмінювати слова, що відсутні у словниках?

Tags: запозичені-слова, відмінювання, іншомовні-слова

Ось є, наприклад, слово под. Це запозичення з англійської.

Чи правильно буде сказати так?

> Щоб додати юзера, треба підключитись до пода

Тут я маю на увазі под Kubernetes.

Які тут точні правила, щоб визначитись, яке саме має бути закінчення слова у родовому відмінку?

Comment: Норми відмінювань становлює не словники (хоча вони можуть вказувати це), а радше правопис.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Слід застосовувати правило
[Відмінювання слів іншомовного походження 2 відміни однини](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A0%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%B9_%D0%B2%D1%96%D0%B4%D0%BC%D1%96%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BA_%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B8_%D1%96%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BA%D1%96%D0%B2_%D1%87%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%96%D1%87%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE_%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B4%D1%83_%D0%B4%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%97_%D0%B2%D1%96%D0%B4%D0%BC%D1%96%D0%BD%D0%B8#%D0%97%D0%B0%D0%BA%D1%96%D0%BD%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8F_-%D1%83,_-%D1%8E):

Закінчення **-а, -я** чи **-у, -ю** **?**

**п.9** Терміни іншомовного походження, які означають елементи будови чогось, конкретні предмети, геометричні фігури та їх частини, а також українські за походженням суфіксальні слова-терміни мають закінчення (**-а, -я**);

**п.18**    Терміни іншомовного походження, що означають фізичні або хімічні процеси, частину площі та ін., а також літературознавчі терміни  мають закінчення (**-у, -ю**).

То ж, вірно,

> Щоб додати юзера, треба підключитись до под**а** **Kubernetes**.